Deploying Flutter web on Github Page："Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'."
I deployed a Flutter web application on GitHub Pages, but when I open the website in Edge and Chrome, it shows a blank page.  I found the following error through the browser's developer tools:
enter image description here
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.
flutter.js:110 Loading app from service worker.
main.dart.js:18616 Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic

And I googled it but did not find a useful answer.
below is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/pozxy/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="pozxy">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>pozxy</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

my github repository is :https://github.com/Pengou22/pozxy/tree/gh-pages
my github page is:https://pengou22.github.io/pozxy/
I'm not sure where the error lies, so I'm unsure what information to provide. If you need it, I can provide it immediately.
Your guidance is much appreciated!
wish to find a successful answer

Is your app trying to use XHR to access a third-party website?  If so, CORS will properly stomp in and prevent you, unless the third-party website announces itself as wide-open.

Thank you for your answer, but I did not access any third-party sites, this is only a blog static site.
